# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Tags: android

Sou iniciante e toda vez que tento fazer o meu aplicativo rodar da erro, por favor me ajudem tenho que acabar isso o mais rapido possivel

```
package com.example.chuveiroappuva;

import com.example.chuveiroappuva.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;


public class ChuveiroAppUVA extends Activity {

    EditText editText1;
    EditText editText2;
    EditText editText3;
    EditText editText4;
    CheckBox checkBox1;
    RadioButton radio0;
    RadioButton radio1;
    RadioButton radio2;
    RadioButton radio3;
    RadioButton radio4;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chuveiro_app_uv);

        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        radio0 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        radio1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        radio2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        radio3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
        radio4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio4);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
            }
        });

        int numero =0, quantidade =0, banhos = 0;
        numero = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
        quantidade = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
        banhos = numero * quantidade;
        editText3.setText(String.valueOf(banhos));

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            private boolean eletrico;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                int numero =0, quantidade =0, banhos = 0;
                double cm;
                numero = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
                quantidade = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
                //Verificação de Chuveiro
                if(checkBox1.isChecked()){
                    setEletrico(true);
                }
                else{
                    setEletrico(false);
                }
                //Processamento
                quantidade = numero * banhos;
                editText3.setText(String.valueOf(banhos));
                cm= 14.88 * numero * banhos;


                if(radio0.isChecked()){
                    cm = 14.88 * numero * banhos;
                }
                else if(radio1.isChecked()){
                    cm = 20.93 * numero * banhos;
                }
                else if(radio2.isChecked()){
                    cm = 25.58 * numero * banhos;
                }
                else if(radio3.isChecked()){
                    cm = 27.90 * numero * banhos;
                }
                else if(radio4.isChecked()){
                    cm = 34.88 * numero * banhos;
                }
                editText4.setText(String.valueOf(cm));

            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public boolean isEletrico() {
                return eletrico;
            }

            public void setEletrico(boolean eletrico) {
                this.eletrico = eletrico;
            }




            });
    }
}
```

Erro apresentado:

```
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738): Process: com.example.chuveiroappuva, PID: 3738
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chuveiroappuva/com.example.chuveiroappuva.ChuveiroAppUVA}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at com.example.chuveiroappuva.ChuveiroAppUVA.onCreate(ChuveiroAppUVA.java:54)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
06-11 22:47:18.216: E/AndroidRuntime(3738):     ... 11 more
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="ChuveiroAppUVA Por UVA" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Numero de Pessoas"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >
    android:text="1"/>


    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Quantidade de Banhos Pessoa"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />
    android:text="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Calcular" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Banhos Tomados Diariamente"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />
    android:text="1"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Eletrico?" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Calcular" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="3200W" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:text="4500W" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/radio1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radio1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="5500W" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:text="6000W" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="7500W" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:text="Custo Mensal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    android:text="1"/>
```

Comment: pelo que pude ver do seu código, provavelmente deve ser porque voce esta tentando converter um valor para inteiro de um edittext vazio, tenta por um valor default nele na declaração do seu activity.xml, tipo: `<EditText ... android:inputType="number" android:ems="10" android:text="1" />` se funcionar avisa, se não, avisa tambem pra gente tentar resolver.

Comment: eu fiz so que continuou o mesmo erro

Comment: posta o arquivo .xml do seu layout que eu testo aqui e posto o resultado

Comment: Ou entaum, pega primeiro o valor do edittext em uma string `String txt1 = editText1.getText().toString();` e depois converte esse valor para int `numero = Integer.parseInt(text1));` e marca um breakpoint e debuga para ver os valores que estão sendo passados no seu codigo.

Comment: não estou conseguindo fazer essa mudança tem como me ajudar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce está fazendo isso errado, aqui está o seu .xml corrigido:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="ChuveiroAppUVA Por UVA" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Numero de Pessoas"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="1">
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Quantidade de Banhos Pessoa"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Calcular" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Banhos Tomados Diariamente"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" 
    android:text="1"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Eletrico?" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Calcular" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="3200W" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:text="4500W" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/radio1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radio1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="5500W" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:text="6000W" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="7500W" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:text="Custo Mensal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
    android:text="1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Aqui um print da tela do app rodando no meu emulador, um 4.7 inc com api 22.

[image]
espero que ajude!

Comment: a tela ficou toda cinza depois que mudei xml e o meu layout sumiu

Comment: reverte o teu código e copia só os componentes do primeiro textview até `<\RelativeLayout>` porque eu tive de usar esse pra testar aqui

Comment: Armando ele funcionou so que ele não faz nenhum tipo de calculo, o que pode ser??

Comment: bem, dai voce precisa rever o seu código ai, faz o que te falei, debuga o seu codigo

Comment: não sei como funciona esse debug, mais eu fiz e não adiantou.

Comment: agora esta fazendo foi um bobo meu, mais não estou conseguindo usar os radiobutton direito eles não deseleciona quando clico em outro